# Position div at the bottom of page or screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a footer section which is placed at the bottom of my webpage. I ran into a problem when the content of my webpage is smaller than the height of the browser viewport, which leaves a blank space between the footer and the end of the page. I tried to solve it by using this piece of css.

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 125px;
}
```

It worked perfectly on my webpages with little content but for big webpages, the footer had overlapped the content. I followed a few online tutorials but I still can't make it right.

```
<body class="bg-1">
<div class="container-full">
    <div class="container">
        ...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer text-center">
   ...
</div>
</body>

.container-full {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto 125px;
}
.bg-1 {
  background: url(../img/1.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 125px;
}
```

I am using Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: change to position:fixed

Comment: Add margin-top:125px;  margin the height of your div

Comment: @NagaSaiA I don't want it to be sticky.

Comment: @RobinPanta It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following Method:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container-full {
  table-layout: fixed;
  background: #ccc;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  display: table-footer-group;
  background: #2f2f2f;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="bg-1">
  <div class="container-full">
    <div class="container">
      <p>Main Content goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer text-center">
      <p>Footer text goes here..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. Can you explain to me what does `height: 1%` do?

Comment: @Jeremy These properties like `height: 1%` and `width: 100%` for correct working of this method is some old firefox browsers. You can ignore them if you want -:)

Comment: If I remove the height property, it doesn't work on my latest firefox browser.

Comment: @Jeremy hmm, I think better use it for cross browser issues.